# Android, how to get message of notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have following code:

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Log.i(TAG, "===> " + extras.toString());
        if (extras != null) {
            String message = (String) extras.get("mainKey");
            // notifies user
            Log.i(TAG, message);
        }
    }
```

I can get message from server but I think `extras.get("mainKey");` has problem because it returns null (i think).
Logcat shows this logs:

```
05-07 16:01:53.666: I/GCMIntentService(10959): Received message
05-07 16:01:53.671: I/GCMIntentService(10959): ===> Bundle[{title=Hesam has sent you a message., collapse_key=do_not_collapse, conversation_id=90, msg_id=456, user_id=22, from=1014390164590, type=message}]
05-07 16:01:53.671: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10959): Releasing wakelock
05-07 16:01:53.676: W/dalvikvm(10959): threadid=33: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c571f8)
05-07 16:01:53.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10959): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-1014390164590-1]
05-07 16:01:53.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10959): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
05-07 16:01:53.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10959):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
05-07 16:01:53.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10959):    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:190)
05-07 16:01:53.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10959):    at com.belldigital.utility.Log.i(Log.java:16)
05-07 16:01:53.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10959):    at com.belldigital.fancied.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:71)
05-07 16:01:53.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10959):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
05-07 16:01:53.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10959):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
05-07 16:01:53.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10959):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 16:01:53.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10959):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 16:01:53.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10959):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I can see what I sent from server but `extras.get("mainKey");` doesn't return anything.
Does anyone have faced this issue before?
Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you see the log that you print before extras != null check, it shows the entries in the intent. Also that line should be after the null pointer check. Do you sent the "mainKey" value in the gcm broadcast ?

Comment: Hi Ashwini, thanks for your comment. I'm not setting "mainKey" in broadcast. I expect that GCM should introduce it. Although I'm using the last update of this library, I afraid this word has been defined over there differently. Is it possible?

Comment: Where is "mainKey" in your received intent printed above as Bundle ==> " ". thats why you can't get it with extras.get("mainKey"). And remember one more thing whenever your trying to data from key first check i.e. is it really part of received message by contains/has.

Comment: Exactly this is my answer, @AndroidNewwbie. Thanks and please put it as answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

use
 `intent.getExtras().getString("mainKey");`

and also make sure that your use

```
 $message= array("mainKey" => $message);
```

and then pass it as data in fields

```
$fields = array(
 'registration_ids' => $registation_ids,
 'data' => $message,
);
```

while sending message from server